# What are the security implications of using Vault with an unencrypted Consul backend?

Tags: security, consul, hashicorp-vault

Suppose I have a 3 node Consul cluster using unencrypted RPC, HTTP API and gossip traffic and a 3 node Vault cluster each talking to a corresponding Consul instance over localhost. What are the security implications of this assuming no unauthorised access to Vault itself?

In particular, since Vault encrypts all data before persisting it to the storage backend, am I right in saying the data persisted by Vault is no more secure than if all Consul traffic was fully encrypted?

Are there any other security implications to consider with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the data between the storage backend and Vault always transits encrypted, so it should be safe. However, rememeber that only the Vault data is encrypted, any other informations transits in plaintext. It's always better to use a secure connection to fully encrypt the communications, even if the secret data is encrypted